# Vectorize/speed-up exponentially weighted covariance calculation in R

Tags: performance, r

I have the following 2-column data.frame:

```
Data <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100),ncol = 2))
```

I would like to calculate the variance-covariance matrix as the exponentially weighted average of the past squared/cross observations (on an expanding window):

[image]

Where delta is set to be 60/61. Thus, at t=4, the sum runs from 1 to 4, and the averages are computed over the first 4 observations. I have managed to implement a function calculating the upper triangular part of the covariance matrix, but it is quite slow. Does anyone have ideas to improve the speed?

```
rollEWCov <- function(Data){      
  res <- c()
  for(i in 1:nrow(Data)){ # Expanding window of data used to calc covariances
    means <-  colMeans(Data[1:i,])
    Cov <- matrix(0,nrow = ncol(Data),ncol=ncol(Data))
    for(k in 1:ncol(Data)){ # first data-column
      l <- k
      while(l <= ncol(Data)){ # second data-column
        Sum <- 0
        for(j in 1:i){ # calc sum of exponentially weighted average of past returns
          Sum <- Sum + (1-60/61)*(60/61)^(j-1)*(Data[i-(j-1),k] - means[k])*(Data[i-(j-1),l] - means[l])
        }
        Cov[k,l] <- Sum
        l <- l + 1
      }
    }
    res[[i]] <- Cov
  }
  return(res)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A key performance bottleneck in your code is your calculation of the Cov_t^{k,l} values:

```
Sum <- 0
for(j in 1:i){ # calc sum of exponentially weighted average of past returns
  Sum <- Sum + (1-60/61)*(60/61)^(j-1)*(Data[i-(j-1),k] - means[k])*(Data[i-(j-1),l] - means[l])
}
Cov[k,l] <- Sum
```

You are summing from j=1 through j=i by looping through the values individually and adding them up. In R you can get significant speedups by using the vectorized `sum` function:

```
Cov[k,l] <- sum((1-60/61)*(60/61)^(0:(i-1))*(Data[i:1,k] - means[k])*(Data[i:1,l] - means[l]))
```

Additionally, this part of the code hard-codes the choice of delta=60/61, which may make it harder to see what the code is doing or update to another delta value. It would be best to pass `delta` to the function and then use `delta` instead of `60/61` in this expression. Here is the updated function:

```
rollEWCovMod <- function(Data, delta){      
  res <- c()
  for(i in 1:nrow(Data)){ # Expanding window of data used to calc covariances
    means <-  colMeans(Data[1:i,])
    Cov <- matrix(0,nrow = ncol(Data),ncol=ncol(Data))
    for(k in 1:ncol(Data)){ # first data-column
      l <- k
      while(l <= ncol(Data)){ # second data-column
        # calc sum of exponentially weighted average of past returns
        Cov[k,l] <- sum((1-delta)*delta^(0:(i-1))*(Data[i:1,k] - means[k])*(Data[i:1,l] - means[l]))
        l <- l + 1
      }
    }
    res[[i]] <- Cov
  }
  return(res)
}
```

To see the performance improvements of the vectorized sum, we can benchmark with a 500 x 2 matrix:

```
Data <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1000),ncol = 2))
system.time(rollEWCov(Data))
#    user  system elapsed 
#  11.300   0.103  12.031 
system.time(rollEWCovMod(Data, 60/61))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.142   0.006   0.149 
all.equal(rollEWCov(Data), rollEWCovMod(Data, 60/61))
# [1] TRUE
```

We obtained a 80x speedup and got identical results to the original function.

Answer (score 3):

While using `sum()` helps a lot (as [josliber did](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/174803/90251)), you can get another 2 orders of magnitude of performance improvement by removing two of the loops. You can replace them with a call to `crossprod()`.  Using a matrix instead of a data.frame is also helpful for performance.  Functions and timings below (the other two functions are also byte-compiled).

```
rollEWCovMod2 <- compiler::cmpfun(function(Data, delta) {
  mat <- as.matrix(Data)  # matrix is often faster than data.frame
  nc <- ncol(mat)         # only calculate number of cols once
  nr <- nrow(mat)         # only calculate number of rows once
  out <- vector("list", nr)  # pre-allocate output

  # Expanding window of data used to calc covariances
  for (i in seq_len(nr)) {
    # sequence of observation locations
    one..i <- seq_len(i)
    # subset matrix one time
    mat_subset <- mat[one..i, , drop = FALSE]
    # column means
    means <- matrix(.colMeans(mat_subset, i, nc), i, nc, byrow = TRUE)
    # subtract the column mean from each column
    scaled <- mat_subset - means
    #scaled <- scale(mat_subset, center = TRUE, scale = FALSE)
    # calculate exponential weights
    wts <- (1-delta) * delta^(-one..i + i)
    # caclulate crossproduct
    res <- crossprod(scaled*wts, scaled)
    dimnames(res) <- NULL     # remove row and column names
    res[lower.tri(res)] <- 0  # set lower values to zero
    # store result
    out[[i]] <- res
  }
  return(out)
})
```

Reproducible example and timings.

```
set.seed(21)
Data <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(4000), ncol = 20))
delta <- 60/61
system.time(r1 <- rollEWCov(Data))
#    user  system elapsed 
# 120.788   0.008 120.879 
system.time(r2 <- rollEWCovMod(Data, delta))
#    user  system elapsed 
#     2.1     0.0     2.1 
system.time(r3 <- rollEWCovMod2(Data, delta))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.024   0.000   0.025 
all.equal(r1, r2)
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(r1, r3)
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(r2, r3)
# [1] TRUE
```